# Is podman's container exec_died message an error?

Tags: podman, rhel9

I see the following two messages in my syslog at regular intervals.  The "exec_died" message sounds like a bad thing, yet everything seems to be working.  Is this an indication of a problem - or just normal for podman?

```
Oct 15 11:39:10 lserver podman[1241533]: 2023-10-15 11:39:10.347507537 -0400 EDT m=+0.128529422 container health_status aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57 (image=docker.io/jacobalberty/unifi:latest, name=unifi, health_status=healthy, jacobalberty/unifi:latest=, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu, org.opencontainers.image.version=18.04, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4.162=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4.162=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4=, maintainer=Jacob Alberty <jacob.alberty@foundigital.com>, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:latest=)
Oct 15 11:39:10 lserver podman[1241533]: 2023-10-15 11:39:10.403101953 -0400 EDT m=+0.184123842 container exec_died aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57 (image=docker.io/jacobalberty/unifi:latest, name=unifi, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4.162=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:latest=, jacobalberty/unifi:latest=, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu, org.opencontainers.image.version=18.04, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4.162=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4=, maintainer=Jacob Alberty <jacob.alberty@foundigital.com>)
```

What exactly is dieing?

Comment: The docs indicate it's only generated when an exec session dies. Do you have any podman exec commands running prior to this event? I can't verify the expected behavior on my system at the moment, but you may be able to test the behavior by running an exec with a program that returns a code 0 vs the behavior for terminating an exec mid execution.

Comment: No, this container is started as a service after network services are up.  The "container exec_died" text seems to reference something container or podman specific (not generic exec/fork process returning non-zero).